# Polygons not displayed properly. Grey colour above the data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I am trying to import a shape file cotaining Wind data over Sweden. I have to zoom in very much to be able to view the data under the grey colour that appears. I figure it has to do something with the border of the polygons but after having had them disabled the problem still remains.

If I zoom out with the globe button I first get the desired format (See picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnEiu.jpg) but as the whole loading is completed the gray layer appears above it (See picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDT7h.jpg) and it is making it impossible for me to begin analysing the data.
GIF of how it appears when I zoom out: https://i.imgur.com/2Xj5iRB.gifv
Why does it appear grey and how can I view it as portrayed in the first photo?
[image: picture2][image: picture1]
I am rather new to GIS so this could be a very "easy" fix.

Comment: Are your data in shapefile format (ie. a file with a .shp extension and a few of other companion file with the same name and different extension); if yes how do you add it ? if not what format are your data in ? also some info on the symbology of your data would help. A first idea is that you get a Sweden shaped polygon that draw on top, if so changing the drawing order could help....

Comment: Hi @J.R and thank you for taking the time to reply to me. The data set is a .shp file accompined with .dbf, .prj, .lock and .shx. I got it from the ministry of energy in Sweden. Can be found here: http://www.energimyndigheten.se/fornybart/vindkraft/planering-och-tillstand/vindkraftsplanering1/nationell-vindkartering/ on the right under 'dokument'.

I added a .gif in the original post to see how it appears on my screen. So strange..
Symbology: The blue to red colour is the speed of the wind.

Comment: I tried with the 80m set (in QGIS) and it seem to be the polygon border that cause the problem, make sure that you set the border of ALL symbol to no color/no width

Comment: Hi again and thanks for trying it for yourself. As I mentioned above I tried to disable all the borders but my problem remained. Did you get a nice view on QGIS?

Comment: Hi again J.R.
I downloaded the file again from the beginning and disabled the border. It did work now. Typical... 
I am excited to develop my understanding of GIS as it seems to be a powerful tool. It is no fun when one gets stuck on these type of problems but having solved it now I am excited to now start analysing the wind data. Thanks again for your help. Have a nice evening/day.